# Loop results to array

Tags: nim-lang

I just started with Nim yesterday. My goal is to calculate a mean of values in the expression b[i]/a[i]. I tried to use math module and built-in function "mean" but apparently it works only with arrays. I don't know how to parse results of my loop into an array (or maybe there is a different solution? Any help appreciated!

```
var a = @[100.0,102.0,101.0,114.0, 128.0, 130.0, 127.0]
var b = a [1..high(a)]&a[high(a)]


 for i in low(a)..high(a):


  echo i+1," period ", "= ", (b[i]/a[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part is to make a new sequence with `var c = newSeq[float]()` and add values to it with `c.add(value)`, as in the first block here:

```
var a = @[100.0, 102.0, 101.0, 114.0, 128.0, 130.0, 127.0]
var b = a[1..a.high] & a[a.high]

import math

block: # Iterative with math.mean
  var c = newSeq[float]()

  for i in a.low..a.high:
    c.add(b[i]/a[i])

  echo mean(c)

block: # Iterative without math.mean (most efficient)
  var myMean = 0.0

  for i in a.low..a.high:
    myMean += b[i]/a[i]

  myMean /= a.len.float
  echo myMean

import sequtils

block: # Functionally (not really nim-like)
  echo zip(a, b).map(proc(x): float = x.b/x.a).mean
```